# How do I insert a block into a node?

Tags: nodes, blocks

I can't insert a block into an article on Drupal 8.

I installed the module, created a custom block, created an article using the *Full HTML* input format, inserted `[block:block=1]` into the article body, and saved it.
Nothing happened. `[block:block=1]` appears in the text instead of the desired block. I tried to find something in admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html to make Drupal recognize the inserted blocks, but I found nothing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert block module implements an "input filter" via the core [Filter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/filter/overview) module. A text format is a collection of enabled input filters. So when enabling a module that provides an input filter, the next step would be to configure the text format to *use* the input filter.

The Full HTML text format does not have that input filter enabled by default.

In addition the module has a Drupal 8 development release, but the code underneath still seems to use PSR-0 for its class loading and has not been updated in *3 years*. It may be [broken for other reasons](https://www.drupal.org/node/2648496) as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new patch (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-06-08/2648496-46.patch) for `insert_block` and now the module works very well. I've tested it on a new Drupal 8.5.5 install.

See this issue for more information : https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block/issues/2648496#comment-12644966

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hook_preprocess_page, put the block into a variable and then you print that variable in your template file (like this: {{ variable_with_the_block }} ).

Comment: How can I use this inside a node body?